# Why doesn't child QGraphicsObject repaint its background correctly

Tags: qt

[image]

The QGraphicsObject in green rectangle, it is the parent of the QGraphicsObject in red rectangle.

```
childInRed->setParentItem(this);
```

When I drag the parent object in green rect and move it fast, the background of the child object in red rect is not repainted correctly.
[image]

I know I can use update in the parent's mouseMoveEvent force the child to repaint. But this is not good, because I don't need to repaint the parent at all.

---

```
#include "asdf.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QGraphicsScene>
#include <QtWidgets/QGraphicsView>

#include <QtWidgets>

class CTestGraphicsObject : public QGraphicsObject
{
public:
    QColor m_c;
    CTestGraphicsObject(QColor c)
        : QGraphicsObject(NULL)
        , m_c(c)
    {
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable, true);
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

        auto effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
        effect->setOffset(4, 4);
        effect->setBlurRadius(20);

        setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    }
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const override
    {
        auto rc = QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100);
        return rc;
    }
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(m_c));
        painter->drawRect(this->boundingRect());
    }
};

asdf::asdf(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    auto s = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    auto v = new QGraphicsView;
    v->setScene(s);

    CTestGraphicsObject* pParent = new CTestGraphicsObject(Qt::green);
    CTestGraphicsObject* pChild = new CTestGraphicsObject(Qt::red);
    pChild->setParentItem(pParent);
    pChild->setPos(0, 100);
    s->addItem(pParent);
    s->addItem(pChild);

    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout(this->centralWidget());
    l->addWidget(v);
}

asdf::~asdf()
{

}
```

The QGraphicsDropShadowEffect causes this problem, It seems I'm not using it in right way.

Comment: @eyllanesc while make the minimal example, I figure out what causes this. Please see my update

Comment: What update? When you have a question: *I have a problem with my code* then you must provide an MCVE

Comment: @eyllanesc, oh, sorry for that, I'm trying making it.

Comment: If you want help you must provide an [MCVE], the code you provide is not.

Comment: @eyllanesc, updated

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect), the scene uses the *bounding rect and region* to define the area to repainted when an item is updated (moved in your case).

If you child is outside its parent, the scene will miss some part when repainting...

Extend the *bouding rect/region* to cover its children.

If you do something like that, it will work:

```
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const override
    {
        if (this->childrenBoundingRect().isEmpty()) // No children
            return QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100);
        return QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100).united(this->childrenBoundingRect());
    }
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(m_c));
        painter->drawRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100));
    }
```